# excel macro cant recognize my second IF condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to check if the cells starting from E15 are having date different of more than 45 day when comparing to today's date, the problem here is that it cant recognize the following condition and it will return error, the below was to check if the cell's value is date. Anything wrong to the below if condition?

```
IsDate(.Range("E" & i)) = True





Sub Refees()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, OutputRow As Long
Dim copyRng As Range

'~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Warranty Quote 1 Year")

With ws
    '~~> Get LatRow in Col B
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    OutputRow = lRow + 1

    '~~> Loop through the cells
    For i = 15 To lRow
        If DateDiff("d", .Range("E" & i).Value, Date) > 45 And IsDate(.Range("E" & i)) = True Then
            If copyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set copyRng = .Range("B" & i & ":I" & i)
            Else
                Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Range("B" & i & ":I" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Copy the expired records in one go
    If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
        copyRng.Copy .Range("B" & OutputRow)

        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("I" & OutputRow & ":I" & lRow).Value = "Reinstatement Fees"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the error is type mismatch

Comment: It's working fine for me. I think you are not putting date in E15 on wards less than current date. Example.: Current date is 12/31/2013 and the value in E15 on wards must be less than current date, i.e. 6/1/2013. Date format is MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful to me too

Comment: @user3045580, if you are benefited by my answer then please mark one up. This would get me few points because, I am restricted from asking question. And I need 6 more points to get rid from restriction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to this (check whether it is a date at first):

```
For i = 15 To lRow
   If IsDate(.Range("E" & i)) = True Then
        If DateDiff("d", .Range("E" & i).Value, Date) > 45 Then
            If copyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set copyRng = .Range("B" & i & ":I" & i)
            Else
                Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Range("B" & i & ":I" & i))
            End If
        End If
   End If 
Next i
```

Comment: thank you, just simple as that, but was wondering why the above function is not working because I was told to use that to make the coding not that messy, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The error occurs because if you use `If DateDiff("d", .Range("E" & i).Value, Date) > 45 And IsDate(.Range("E" & i)) = True Then` statement, at first, it tries to calculate DateDiff() (which throw an error) and only then it checks whether your range contains correct date

Comment: Your `If +And` approach didn't work because you simultaneously test the range under different but dependent conditions. `And` really helps improve code and faster too but don't test the same object or variable if possible specially if one condition is dependent to the other.